# Inno Setup avoiding duplicate registry entries for path?

Tags: inno-setup

I created an installer where it also adds onto the `path` for Environment.
But let's say we install the software twice, it would also insert twice on the registry which I don't want to happen.

I tried using the Flag: `createvalueifdoesntexist` but it seems it doesn't work, as even there is no value that is the same, it won't insert.

This what happens...

1st Installation:

```
C:\Test
```

2nd Installation:

```
C:\Test; C:\Test
```

This what inside my `[registry]` section:

```
Root: HKA; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; 
   ValueType:string; ValueName: "PathTest"; ValueData: "{olddata}; {app}\ASA";
   Flags: preservestringtype createvalueifdoesntexist
```

(formatted with linebreaks for readability)

Comment: [PathMgr.dll](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PathMgr) has this functionality (don't add to Path if it's already there).